# How to get image resource size in bytes with PHP and GD?

Tags: php, image, gd

I'm resizing images with php gd. The result is image resources that i want to upload to Amazon S3. It works great if i store the images on disk first but i would like to upload them directly from memory. That is possible if i just know the bytesize of the image.

Is there some way of getting the size (in bytes) of an gd image resource?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use PHP's [memory i/o stream](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) to save the image to and subsequently get the size in bytes.

What you do is:

```
$img = imagecreatetruecolor(100,100);
// do your processing here
// now save file to memory
imagejpeg($img, 'php://memory/temp.jpeg'); 
$size = filesize('php://memory/temp.jpeg');
```

Now you should know the size

I don't know of any (gd)method to get the size of an image resource.

Comment: The problem is that the `gd` functions expect a path, not a file resource, to write to. This should work with [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) instead though.

Comment: @deceze: You should be able to supply a path like: `php://memory/resource=img.jpeg`

Comment: Ah nice one! This will use double the memory though so it's not optimal but a nice alternative :)

Answer (score 11):

I can't write on php://memory with imagepng, so I use ob_start(), ob_get_content() end ob_end_clean()

```
$image = imagecreatefrompng('./image.png'); //load image
// do your processing here
//...
//...
//...
ob_start(); //Turn on output buffering
imagejpeg($image); //Generate your image

$output = ob_get_contents(); // get the image as a string in a variable

ob_end_clean(); //Turn off output buffering and clean it
echo strlen($output); //size in bytes
```

Comment: Why not use `ob_get_length` like @JonathanWren suggested?

Answer (score 9):

This also works:

```
$img = imagecreatetruecolor(100,100);

// ... processing

ob_start();              // start the buffer
imagejpeg($img);         // output image to buffer
$size = ob_get_length(); // get size of buffer (in bytes)
ob_end_clean();          // trash the buffer
```

And now `$size` will have your size in bytes.

Comment: Thank you. This helped me because i needed a way to determine the file size without uploading it.

Answer (score 0):

You might look at the following answer for help.  It works for generic memory changes in php.
Although since overhead could be involved it might be more of an estimation.

[Getting size of PHP objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351855/getting-size-in-memory-of-an-object-in-php)

Answer (score -1):

Save the image file in the desired format to a tmp dir, and then use filesize() http://php.net/manual/de/function.filesize.php before uploading it to S3 from disk.

Comment: Here is the English version: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php  :)

Comment: Saving a temp-file on disk is exactly what i'm trying to avoid here.

Comment: Why? It's not that much a performance issue and saves a lot of RAM.