# PHP: Getting image file size from resource (before uploading)?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get image resource size in bytes with PHP and GD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023441/how-to-get-image-resource-size-in-bytes-with-php-and-gd)

```
$resource = imagecreatefromstring(stream_get_contents($fhandle));
```

I will save this image on my server with createjpeg() but I want to check the file size before saving it.

How can this be done?

Comment: [getimagesizefromstring](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesizefromstring.php) This might not be the best solution, but I think it'd work.

Comment: @GiantofaLannister, That's not what is needed here.  The file size is what is being asked for.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think to do this would be with output buffering.

Enable the output buffer with [`ob_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php), output the image, and then check the length with [`ob_get_length()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-length.php).  Then, if the file is within your limits, you can use [`ob_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php) and write it to disk without having to re-render the image again.

Caution though, this could take quite a bit of memory, as with any image operations.