# PHP: How can I get the size in bytes of dynamically generated image in php?

Tags: php, size, filesize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get image resource size in bytes with PHP and GD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023441/how-to-get-image-resource-size-in-bytes-with-php-and-gd)

Is it possible to get the file size (not the image size dimensions) of object $image using php? I would like to add this to my "Content-Length:" header.

```
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($reqFilename);
```

Comment: You should read more about the http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php like `ob_start()`, `ob_clean()`, `ob_flush()`, etc

Answer (score 3):

I think this should work:

```
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg($reqFilename);

// capture output
ob_start();

// send image to the output buffer
imagejpeg($img);

// get the size of the o.b. and set your header
$size = ob_get_length();
header("Content-Length: " . $size);

// send it to the screen
ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: +1 for the `ob_` part, but if the file is already stored on disk, simply doing `filesize()` will do just fine. If he would resize, cropping or doing some other manipulation before sending the image to the browser, then your solution clearly the best=)

Comment: It depends upon which image is he displaying. If it's not the original one, then the file sizes will differ, because gd will recompress the jpeg...

Comment: I need to set the header before the "imagejpeg($new_image);"

Comment: yes even with 100% quality... it will output a different filesize.

Comment: Why? No headers are sent during output buffering. @Krister: Can't answer that as I haven't tested it. I would assume it does

Comment: @OneTrickPony - I agree, with buffering enabled no headers should be set, so I think it will work?

Comment: Pony: for the same reason you wouldn't send your "header("Content-type: image/jpeg");" after the imagejpeg($img);

Comment: Again, no headers are sent if the output is sent to the internal buffer, so you can safely set your headers after printing, as long as you do it before you flush the buffer

Comment: I just tried it and it works fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

You could just use [filesize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php) for this:

```
 // returns the size in bytes of the file
 $size = filesize($reqFilename);
```

The above will of course only work if the resized image is the one stored on disk if you will resize the image after your call to `imagecreatefromjpeg()` then you should go with @One Trick Ponys solution and do something like this:

```
  // load original image
  $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
  // resize image
  $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
  imagecopyresampled($new_image, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
  // get size of resized image
  ob_start();
  // put output for image in buffer
  imagejpeg($new_image);
  // get size of output
  $size = ob_get_length();
  // set correct header
  header("Content-Length: " . $size);
  // flush the buffer, actually send the output to the browser
  ob_end_flush();
  // destroy resources
  imagedestroy($new_image);
  imagedestroy($image);
```

Comment: Just add a note that dynamically generated images should be first stored in a file on the server in order to use `filesize` before sending it to the client.

Comment: that will only get the size of the stored image. however what if I modify the image... size will change.

Comment: I need to set the header before the "imagejpeg($new_image);".