# Calculate Memory Usage of Array in PHP

Tags: php

I am aware that I can get the memory used with

> memory_get_peak_usage();

but is there a way to tell in advance how much memory an array will need?

Thanks!

Comment: Check this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351855/getting-size-in-memory-of-an-object-in-php
Simmilar problem solved

Comment: Thanks but I am looking for a way to get the memory needed BEFORE executing the function. So I want to calculate the estimated memory needed beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with a built-in function.

You need to know what is beeing stored inside the array and from that on you could calculate the memory needed.